# Column mapping with Abstract class (TPT with existing tables)

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework-4, ef-code-first

I am developing against existing DB, having problem mapping my abstract class to my table as TPT., which raised an error saying "invalid column name "ID"".

Simple class as follows

```
public abstract class Member 
{
    [DisplayName("ID")]
    public string ID { get; set; }

    [DisplayName("Date Applied")]
    public System.DateTime? DateApplied { get; set; }

    [DisplayName("Date Membered")]
    public System.DateTime? DateMembered { get; set; }

    [DisplayName("Member Type")]
    public int MemberTypeFlag { get; set; }

}


public class Person : Member
{
    [DisplayName("Last Name")]
    public string LastName { get; set; }

    [DisplayName("First Name")]
    public string FirstName { get; set; }

    [DisplayName("Date Of Birth")]
    public System.DateTime DateOfBirth { get; set; }
}
```

And mapped to my custom table as follows

```
public class MapMember : EntityTypeConfiguration<Member>
{
    public MapMember()
        : base()
    {
        HasKey(b => b.ID).Property(b => b.ID).HasColumnName("ID");
        Property(b => b.DateApplied).HasColumnName("DTM_APPLIED");
        Property(b => b.DateMembered).HasColumnName("DTM_MEMBERED");
        Property(b => b.MemberTypeFlag).HasColumnName("MBR_TYPE_FLG");
        ToTable("MBR");
    }
}

public class MapPerson : EntityTypeConfiguration<Person>
{
    public MapPerson()
        : base()
    {
        Property(p => p.LastName).HasColumnName("LNAME");
        Property(p => p.FirstName).HasColumnName("FNAME");
        Property(p => p.DateOfBirth).HasColumnName("DOB");
        Property(p => p.FirstName).HasColumnName("FNAME");
        ToTable("MBR_PERSON");
    }
}
```

However Invalid column name "ID" raised upon db.savechanges().

Please advise.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

This error will occur if the primary key column in your `MBR_PERSON` table (which must be foreign key to the `MBR` table at the same time) does not have the column name `ID` (the name of the key column in table `MBR`). In TPT mapping the primary key columns of the root table for the abstract entity must have the same name as the primary key columns of the tables for the derived entities.

Comment: Thank you for pointing this out, been figuring this for a couple of days. Would there will be any link for the DOs and Donts for the things like this.

Comment: @roggss: I don't know a really comprehensive resource about this (definitely not about the Donts). But this point is actually a hole in the configuration options of EF Code-First as you can't configure the key column names for the derived entities' tables. I have seen this more than once that people are having problems to create a TPT mapping with an existing database because of this limitation.